# Skip to a database record in c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, record, skip

Here is some background on what I have been following.

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p9.html

That will go to the last or first record of the database. I want to skip to a record in the access database that the user wants by inputting the ID number in a textbox and then the correct row will get put in the textboxes.

I think I can use this code from the above website. I have implemented everything else from the website above.

Global variable

```
int inc = 0;
```

The navigate records that I will call in my Skip button later

```
private void NavigateRecords()
{
      DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc];

      txtMaker.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
      txtModel.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
      txtPrice.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
      txtBids.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
      txtScreen.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString();
      txtCPU.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString();
      txtMemory.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString();
      txtHD.Text = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(8).ToString();
      picLaptops.Image = Image.FromFile(ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc].ItemArray.GetValue(9).ToString());
}
```

My skip button so far...

```
private void btnSkip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigateRecords();           
}
```

It is hard for me to do this. I know what I want but lack the technical skill to do it. It is very frustrating. I have no idea what to do.

If someone can work it out and show me the code I can then understand it and use it elsewhere.

Here is an example of the next button to go to the next record if that helps.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (inc != MaxRows - 1)
      {
            inc++;
            NavigateRecords();
      }
      else
      {
          MessageBox.Show("You have reached the end of available items", "End of Available Items", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I think this is what you want

```
void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int id = Int32.Parse(yourIdTextBox.Text);

    DataRow row = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                     .SingleOrDefault(r => (int)r.ItemArray[your id index] == id);

    if (row == null)
    {
         //user typed in invalid row id
    }  else
          processRow(row);
}

void processRow(DataRow row){
    txtMaker.Text = row.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
    txtModel.Text = row.ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString();
    txtPrice.Text = row.ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString();
    txtBids.Text = row.ItemArray.GetValue(4).ToString();
    txtScreen.Text = row.ItemArray.GetValue(5).ToString();
    txtCPU.Text = row.ItemArray.GetValue(6).ToString();
    txtMemory.Text = row.ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString();
    txtHD.Text = row.ItemArray.GetValue(8).ToString();
    picLaptops.Image = Image.FromFile(row.ItemArray.GetValue(9).ToString());
}
```

Which would then simplify your NavigateRecors() method to

```
private void NavigateRecords()
{
    DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Laptops"].Rows[inc];

    processRow(dRow);
}
```

Comment: I get this error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>' to 'System.Data.DataRow'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: It works but I should have been more specific. It is my fault. Is there anyway to slighlty modify your code so the inc will not start from 0 if I press the Next or Previous button after skipping to an id? eg If I skip to the ID number 9 it will show the item but when I click next it will go to the id of 2 and not the id of 10 (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

Use data binding, instead of assigning values manually to controls.

1. create a model class

```cs
public class MyClass  
{  
    public string Maker { get; set; }  
    public double price { get; set; }  
    // and so on, for all your fields  
}
```

1. Add a object data source for MyClass in the "Data Sources" explorer in Visual Studio.
2. Drag the fields form the Data Sources to your form. Visual Studio automatically add a BindingSource and a BindingNavigator to your form.
3. Assign your data to the BindingSource in the form:

```cs
this.bindingSource1.DataSource = myData;
```

Where myData is some enumeration of MyClass objects.

You can do this for database sources as well. But personally I prefer to have my data in classes. Is's easier to handle, than either manipulating DataSets or form fields directly.